# How to insert bulk data through spark dataframe to Sql Server Data warehouse by using Service Principle using Databricks

Tags: sql-server-2012, apache-spark-sql, data-warehouse, azure-databricks

I'm trying to insert bulk data through spark dataframe to Sql server data warehouse in Databricks. For this i'm using pyodbc module with service principle(not by using jdbc).I have achieved with single insertion.I couldn't find a way to  insert bulk data to sql server data warehouse.Can someone help me a way to insert data in Bulk?

Answer (score 0):

Examples here: https://docs.databricks.com/spark/latest/data-sources/azure/sql-data-warehouse.html

Though this tends to recommend you use a blob storage account between the two.

You can also use the standard SQL interface: https://docs.databricks.com/spark/latest/data-sources/sql-databases.html

But you cannot use a service principal - you will need a SQL Login. I would store a connectionstring in key vault as a secret (using the SQL login). Get the secret using your service principal and then connect to SQL using the connetionstring.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this nicely using polybase, it will require a location to store the temp files:

https://docs.databricks.com/data/data-sources/azure/sql-data-warehouse.html#azure-sql-data-warehouse